# How to create an Angular2 filter pipe that acts such as Angular1 filter?

Tags: angular, filter, pipe, ngfor

I'm developing an Angular2 app and I need to use a filter for some of my `*ngFor` directives.

I created the following `Pipe`:

```
import {Pipe, PipeTransform} from "@angular/core";

@Pipe({
    name: 'filter',
    pure: false
})
export class FilterPipe implements PipeTransform {
    transform(array: Array<Object>, key: string, value: string, negate: boolean): Array<Object> {
        if (array === null || array === undefined) {
            return [];
        } else {
            if (negate) {
                return array.filter(item => item[key] !== value);
            } else {
                return array.filter(item => item[key] === value);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is an example of how I use it:

```
<div class="item" *ngFor="let i of items | filter:'type':'S':true">
```

But it doesn't work if I would to filter for a child property.
With Angular v1.x I could apply the following filter:

`item in array | filter: { type: {subtype: 'foo'}}`

Do you know how can I reach the same with my Angular2 Pipe?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can I ask you what's wrong with my question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

Use this or create your own method to extract deep(or even not deep properties):

```
getProperty(obj: any, path: string): string { 
  if (obj == null || obj.constructor !== Object) {
    return undefined;
  }

  const replaced: string = path.replace(/\[(\w+)\]/g, '.$1').replace(/^\./, '');
  const keys: string[] = replaced.split('.');
  let result: string = obj[keys.shift()];

  for (const key of keys) {
    if (result == null || result.constructor !== Object) {
      return undefined;
    }

    result = result[key];
  }

  return result;
}
```

Now, you adjust your pipe to:

```
@Pipe({
  name: 'filterBy',
  pure: false
})
export class FilterByPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(items: any[], prop: string, term: string, exact: boolean = false): any[] {

    if (!Array.isArray(items) || typeof term !== 'string') {
      return items;
    }

    const strTerm: string = `${term}`.toLowerCase();

    return items.filter((obj: any) => {
      const value: string = this.getProperty(obj, prop);
      if (!value) {
        return false;
      }

      const strValue: string = `${value}`.toLowerCase();  
      return exact
          ? strTerm === strValue
          : strValue.indexOf(strTerm) !== -1;
    });
  }
```

To use it:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of items | filterBy: 'nestedObj.key': search: exact">
```

or

```
<div *ngFor="let item of items | filterBy: 'nestedObj[key]': search: exact">
```

[**DEMO**](http://plnkr.co/edit/FwHtSxJSg5S7BHhSOm8w?p=preview)

### Update#1:

As requested by OP, there's a version that accepts another parameter (`negate`):

```
<div *ngFor="let item of items | filterBy: 'nestedObj.key': search: exact: negate">
```

or

```
<div *ngFor="let item of items | filterBy: 'nestedObj[key]': search: exact: negate">
```

[**DEMO**](http://plnkr.co/edit/zEIcu8TJQzhEeKYwGsPG?p=preview)

---

**PS:** Note that `exact` and `negate` are optionals, if they aren't present, automatically they will be `false`.

Comment: How to add `negate` as parameter?

Comment: Just add the param to the `transform` *method*, and pass it in template.

Comment: So, @smartmouse, have you tested my answer?

Comment: I bookmarked it, I will test it in some hours. Anyway I do not know how to add `negate` because your source code is too hard for me.

Comment: @smartmouse I just added a new plunker that accepts `negate` parameter. Let me know if it works well.

Answer (score 0):

### Here is a working [Plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/eu4nrQGkhWkw5ikBi18r?p=preview) implementing your filter pipe

You just have to make sure you are using the correct template syntax.

```
<span *ngFor="let item of items | filter:'key':'value'">
      {{item}}
</span>
```

Multiple arguments are supported.

Separate each `param` with `:`

```
{{ myData | myPipe: arg1:arg2:arg3... }}
```

Comment: Your Plunker doesn't work (see the console). Anyway as I can see having a look at the source code, there is no use of nested property with filter.

Comment: @smartmouse - have a look now. I was in a hurry earlier didn't have time to test.

Comment: Plunker works now, but as I said before you are filtering by a propery, instead of by a property of a property as I asked in my question.

Comment: @smartmouse I'm sorry your question was quite unclear. I will put something together after my lunch break.

Comment: Can I ask you what's wrong at my question? Anyway thank you for your time, I will wait...